# Explicitly initializing Jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile. I just wanted to stop jquery mobile to do anything unless I explicitly call trigger('create') method. Is there a way to stop jquery mobile auto initialization for some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can do it by adding this attribute:

  ```
  data-enhance="false"
  ```

to a wanted container.

And you also need to turn this on in the app loading phase:

```
$(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true;
});
```

More about this can be found here:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Xjurd/

You can test it by enabling/disabling ***$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true;***

- Second option is to do it manually with this line:

  ```
  data-role="none"
  ```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LqDke/

**EDIT :**

To recreate a page again use this:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow', function (event) {
    $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = false;
    $(this).attr('data-enhance','true');
    $(this).trigger("pagecreate")
});
```

Comment: Now, I need to explicitly invoke jquery mobile to do the initialization. HOw to do it

Comment: Take a look at my "EDIT" segment. Comment a code inside pagebeforeshow event to see how it is working without restyling.