# jQuery Mobile "enhance" dynamically re-generated html

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile 1.2.0

I generate the HTML using JavaScript (`$(selector).html(content)`), add it to the DOM and then display it (`$.mobile.changePage()`).

Then I invoke an AJAX call, get some data, and re-generate the html (but the parent element, the same `$(selector)`, stays the same, I just change its `html(...)`).
**At this poing the HTML is not "enhanced" by jQM, no styling applied on it.**

Now according to the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) I should simply call the `page()` function on the parent element, i.e `$(selector).page()`.

Other places in the docs suggest triggering the `create` event, i.e `$(selector).trigger("create")`.

The problem is that non of the above two methods works - the styling of jQM is not applied.

Looking at the code of jQM, **I've tried triggering the `pagecreate` event on that element and it does work**, but, this is not documented anywhere, so I'm uncertain of it, especially concerning future releases of jQM.

At some poing in the docs I've read that I can call `page()` on a page only once..

Anyway, is there any concise/standard way to tell jQM to "enhance" the whole element and its child-elements? Or should I simply stay with triggering the `pagecreate` event?

Thank you!

Comment: Tell me what kind of content are you adding after the ajax call? A fill page change or just some UI elements like listviews and buttons?

Comment: @Gajotres it's not just adding, it's **replacing** the whole content, including header/footer and the whole content (text,buttons,images etc').

Answer (score 1):

To recreate a whole page use this:

```
$(selector).trigger("pagecreate");
```

This was my answer to a simmilar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011070/1848600. There's an example of page recreation. Take a look, this should probably solve your problem.

Comment: So you suggest it's OK to simply trigger the `pagecreate` event, as I've tried. Since the docs are not clear about it I'd be happy if anyone could back this up as well. Thank you Gajotres though, I appriciate it!

Comment: Tell me is it helping you to restyle the page?

Comment: @Poni, Gajotres is correct, triggering 'pagecreate' is (confusingly) the way you refresh a page/widget in JQM

Answer (score 1):

What is the scope of 
    $(selector).trigger("create");

You should be able to add any elements on the 'pagecreate' event which comes right before  'pageshow' jqm styling is applied to elements. For example I dynamically add a header/footer like this

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', "[data-role=page]", function() {

var header = "<div data-role='header'>some header stuff</div>";
 var footer= "<div data-role='footer'>some footer stuff</div>";

$(this).prepend(header);
$(this).append(footer);

$("[data-role=header]").fixedtoolbar({tapToggle: false});
$("[data-role=footer]").fixedtoolbar({tapToggle: false});

});
```

Make sure you're using jquery 1.7  or above I think that's when the on method was introduced;

It sounds like you may be generating the DOM and then changing the page, try it the other way around go to the page first then dynamically edit the dom.

EDIT
set the reload page option to true

```
  $.mobile.changePage($(page), {reloadPage: true});
```

Edit 2

```
$(selector).children().each(function(){
   $(this).trigger('create');
})
```

Comment: I do put the page on the DOM at first, and about a second after I change its content (`html()`) which includes everything (header/footer etc'). Then I need to re-style that HTML, and that's where my problem is.. I need a generic way to solve it, not just a solution for listview or header/footer because I handle many page like that.

Comment: Are you generating a complete page dynamically or are you navigating to an acutal html page and then adding elements to the dom?

Comment: Look at my edit, try setting the page to force reload on the changepage method

Comment: It's really simple; I generate a page, add it to the DOM, then manipulate its content using `.html(..)`. That's all.

Comment: then theres no reason $(selector).html(data).trigger('create'); wouldn't work on JQM elements

Comment: Ok, so how would you tell jQM to iterate through that element again and find children and enhance them? That's the point I can't figure out.

Comment: Try using the children selector. You should add some actual sample code maybe I can see what elements you're talking about specifically   Look at my second edit